# What is the process of creating a hard fork of Ethereum?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, private-blockchain, hardforks

I am interested in creating a hard fork of Ethereum for production use. The idea is to end up with a separate blockchain similar to Ethereum Classic. As previously stated, I will be using this Ethereum fork for production alongside other Ethereum forks. I don't want a test network, I want a production ready blockchain forked from Ethereum. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you release code and get miners and users (and exchanges and other stakeholders) to use it.

https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs has a list of the hard forks and the links in the Blog column point to the code.